# ASM bytecode manipulation: Measuring method execution speed

Tags: java, bytecode, agent, java-bytecode-asm

I am pretty new to ASM and bytecode manipulation. My task is fairly simple: I tell my agent what class and method to visit and it measures the execution time of that method. The measurment is done with Guava library's Stopwatch class. ASM basically surrounds the method body by starting the Stopwatch at the beginning and stopping it at the end of the method body and printing out the execution time. This has worked on some methods, but has failed on most of them.

This is the part where ASM visits the beginning of the target method.

```
package com.agent.agentclasses;


import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.LocalVariablesSorter;
import org.objectweb.asm.Type;

public class ModifierMethodWriter  extends LocalVariablesSorter /*MethodVisitor*/ {
    private int time;
    protected ModifierMethodWriter(int api, int access, String desc, MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(api, access, desc, mv);
    }


    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        System.out.println("I am @ModifierMethodWriter!");

        /*
        *   Guava - beginning of the method !
        */
        time = newLocal(Type.getObjectType("stopwatch"));


        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/google/common/base/Stopwatch", "createStarted", "()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;", false);

        super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, time);
        super.visitCode();




    }
```

Adding code to the end !

```
package com.agent.agentclasses;

import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class AddCodeBeforeReturn extends AdviceAdapter { 
    public AddCodeBeforeReturn(int api, MethodVisitor mv,
             int acc, String name, String desc){

        super(api, mv, acc, name, desc);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onMethodExit(int opcode) {
        /*
        *   Guava - Before return !
        */
        super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
        super.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 2);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "com/google/common/base/Stopwatch", "stop", "()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;", false);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "com/google/common/base/Stopwatch", "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", false);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
    }
}
```

This is the test class where I want to test my agent: It is HSQL db class and i want to measure the execution time of selectAll() method.

```
package com.agent.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import com.agent.testclasses.*;
public class Database {

    private Connection connection = null;  
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;  
    private Statement statement = null;
    private String createtablestr = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students(Id int,Name varchar(255));";
    private static int id = 1;

    public String connect() {
        System.out.println("I am in connect!");
        try{
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/hsqldb/studentdb", "sa", "");
        if (connection == null)
        {

            return "Error: Connection failed.";
        }
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(createtablestr);
        }catch(Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Connection succesful!";
    }

    public String insert(Student student){
        connect();  
        try {

            String insertStr = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('"+ id +"','"+ student.getName() + "')";
            statement.executeUpdate(insertStr);
            id++;
        }catch(Throwable ex){ex.printStackTrace(); return "Error: Data was not written!";}

        return "Data written succesfully!";
    }   

    public String selectAll() {


        connect();  
        String outputHTML="";
        try{


            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Students");


            while (resultSet.next()) 
            {  
                outputHTML+= "<tr>" + "<td>" + resultSet.getString("Id") + "</td>" + "<td>" + resultSet.getString("Name") + "</td>"  + "</tr>";
            }



            resultSet.close();
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();


        } 
        catch (Throwable e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputHTML;
   }
}
```

And finally, the exception that jvm thorws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 85
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/agent/database/Database.connect()Ljava/lang/String; @85: astore_2
      Reason:
        Type top (current frame, locals[1]) is not assignable to 'stopwatch' (stack map, locals[1])
      Current Frame:
        bci: @12
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'com/agent/database/Database', top, 'com/google/common/base/Stopwatch' }
        stack: { 'java/lang/Throwable' }
      Stackmap Frame:
        bci: @85
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'com/agent/database/Database', 'stopwatch' }
        stack: { 'java/lang/Throwable' }
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: b800 2a4d b200 3212 34b6 003a 123c b800
        0x0000010: 4257 2a12 4412 4612 48b8 004e b500 182a
        0x0000020: b400 18c7 0014 1250 b200 3219 02b6 0053
        0x0000030: b600 56b6 003a b02a 2ab4 0018 b900 5e01
        0x0000040: 00b5 001c 2ab4 001c 2ab4 0020 b900 6402
        0x0000050: 0057 a700 084d 2cb6 0067 1269 b200 3219
        0x0000060: 02b6 0053 b600 56b6 003a b0            
      Exception Handler Table:
        bci [12, 38] => handler: 85
        bci [55, 82] => handler: 85
      Stackmap Table:
        append_frame(@55,Object[#88])
        same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@85,Object[#44])
        same_frame(@90)

        at com.agent.testers.tester1.main(tester1.java:15)
```

It seems to me that after ASM creates new entry in the local variable table for the Stopwatch, jvm tries to overwrite it with the local variables of the method i am trying to target (in this case selectAll()). Therefore:

> Type top (current frame, locals[1]) is not assignable to 'stopwatch'
>   (stack map, locals[1])

I am not sure if this is the actual problem or not, but i need to solve it ! In the end my agent should be plugable with any method. All your help will be appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 'StopWatch' instance in a newly allocated 'time' local variable and then loading its instance from local variable slot 2 and you should be adding your code after 'super.visitCode()'.

Also see [ASM FAQ Why do I get the xxx verifier error](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q4) for more detail how to use [CheckClassAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/CheckClassAdapter.html) to debug your bytecode transformations.

Comment: Hello Eugene ! First of all thank your your response ! Secondly, I am a bit confused because I don'